# How to input a csv file into a Pygal Bar chart

Tags: python, csv, graph, pygal

I am trying to create a barchart showing off the price of spotify premium from different countries around europe. I do not know how to import a csv file to create this graph. this is my current code

```
import pygal as pg
import csv

filename = 'premiumusersEurope.csv'
with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    #print(list(reader))
    pg_bar = pg.Bar()
    for row in reader:
            x.append(int(row[0]))
            y.append(int(row[1]))
    
pg_bar.render_to_file("simple.svg")
```

This code is not working, and i cannot find out why.

[This is my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCfQs.png)
any help will be appriciated

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help :

```
with open(filename, mode='r') as f:
```

or

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
```

or

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
```

or please refer this link :
https://realpython.com/python-csv/